# Activate mobile camera for photo

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I am working with a project that what I want to achieve is that from web, android or IOS can activate the camera and take a picture

In addition to this, I keep it in a database, I currently work with MVC, C #, SQL and for the front part with html and JavaScrip

Any suggestions to do it?

Or some example on which I can base

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a hybride application like [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs) or [React](http://www.reactnative.com/) and you can manipulate the input of camera and mic with [mediaDevices API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices) good luck